# Environment as local namespaces

Tags: macros, environments, grouping

I wish for something quite simple to describe but maybe impossible to have.

I would like to give multiple definitions to a macro (`\U` in my case) such that depending on the environment it can have different meaning.

I would have `enva`, `envb` and `envc` somewhere other definitions for `\Ua`, `\Ub` and `\Uc` so that

```
  \begin{enva}
  Some text, \U some other texts
  \end{enva}
```

expands the same as `Some text, \Ua some other texts`

Comment: What should happen if \U is used e.g. in a tabular inside enva?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I am not sure i understand; in my intention ``enva`` would have no other effect than redefine locally ``\U``.

Comment: See my answer to understand why I wanted to know this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can provide a default definition for `\U` and renew it when the environment starts.

```
\newcommand{\U}{default definition} % maybe issuing error
\newcommand{\Ua}{definition for enva}
\newcommand{\Ub}{definition for envb}
\newcommand{\Uc}{definition for envc}

\newenvironment{enva}
 {\renewcommand{\U}{\Ua}...}
 {...}
\newenvironment{envb}
 {\renewcommand{\U}{\Ub}...}
 {...}
\newenvironment{envc}
 {\renewcommand{\U}{\Uc}...}
 {...}
```

Since environments form groups, the redefinition will end its effect as soon as the environment ends.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Ua{AAA}
\newcommand\Ub{BBB}
\newcommand\Uc{CCC}
\newcommand\U{} % Check that \U is not in use
\newenvironment{enva}{\let\U\Ua}{}
\newenvironment{envb}{\let\U\Ub}{}
\newenvironment{envc}{\let\U\Uc}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{enva}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{enva}

\begin{envb}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{envb}

\begin{envc}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{envc}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe define with a variable that changes between environments.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\definevariable[2][]
  {\providecommand#2{\csuse{_\environmentvariable_\detokenize{#2}}}%
   \expandafter\newcommand\csname\detokenize{_#1_#2}\endcsname}

\definevariable[a]{\U}{whatever}
\definevariable[b]{\U}{whatever else}
\definevariable[c]{\U}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}

\newenvironment{enva}{\def\environmentvariable{a}}{}
\newenvironment{envb}{\def\environmentvariable{b}}{}
\newenvironment{envc}{\def\environmentvariable{c}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{enva}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{enva}

\begin{envb}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{envb}

\begin{envc}
  Some text, \U{some} other texts
\end{envc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry, I cannot compile now, but I believe it's fixed.

Comment: Yes, this way it's compilable.

Answer (score 6):

The definition text can make use of the name of the current environment. But it is unclear if this is useful, as it would change the command in inner environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Uenva{AAA}
\newcommand\Uenvb{BBB}
\newcommand\Uenvc{CCC}

\newcommand\U{\csname U\csname @currenvir\endcsname\endcsname} % 
\newenvironment{enva}{}{}
\newenvironment{envb}{}{}
\newenvironment{envc}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{enva}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{enva}

\begin{envb}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts

  \begin{tabular}{l}
  in tabular empty: \U 
  \end{tabular}
\end{envb}

\begin{envc}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{envc}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Much more complicate then the other ones...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{insideA}
\setboolean{insideA}{false}
\newboolean{insideB}
\setboolean{insideB}{false}
\newboolean{insideC}
\setboolean{insideC}{false}


\newcommand{\U}{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{insideA}}{%
  in A%
}{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{insideB}}{%
    in B%
    }{%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{insideC}}{%
        in C%
        }{%
            default%
}}}}


\newenvironment{enva}{\setboolean{insideA}{true}}{\setboolean{insideA}{false}}
\newenvironment{envb}{\setboolean{insideB}{true}}{\setboolean{insideB}{false}}
\newenvironment{envc}{\setboolean{insideC}{true}}{\setboolean{insideC}{false}}

\begin{document}

Some text, \U\ some other texts

\begin{enva}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{enva}

\begin{envb}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{envb}

\begin{envc}
  Some text, \U\ some other texts
\end{envc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this best, it's what I would've done ;)

Comment: @Moriambar but it gets really tedious when you want to expand it to more environments… (image ten instead of three)

Comment: Of course… but I still like it best. I don't know why, it appeals me.

Comment: While it looks good, it's the worst answer so far. Just use `envb` inside of `enva`. While the macro should be in mode of `envb` it only uses the stuff of `enva`. This is not the desired behavior.

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry to hear that you don't like my answer. But the question did not mention the possibility of nested environments, and without a bit more background information, it is hard to guess what should happen in this case. If envb is inside enva, \U is still used inside enva - so without more specification regarding the macro output, I don't see where the current behaviour is wrong.

Comment: The question was, how to use the environments as namespaces. In my understanding, in that case the behavior should be to use the lowest level.

Comment: @samcarter Definitely not what i was looking for :) but i really liked this answer; I discovered how to use some simple ifs and made me realize that i had not considered the possibility of nested environment.  I will bookmark this for future references, thanks